# How to post photos to tumblr in android?

Tags: android, share, tumblr

I have to post a photo to "tumblr" in a button click. I tried the following way to connect with the tumblr but, unfortunately i didn't got through..!

Is my callback URL correct.? I am getting problem with my call back URL.

```
public class TumblrDemoActivity extends Activity {

private static final String TAG = "TumblrDemo";

private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token";
private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token";
private static final String AUTH_URL = "https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize";

// Taken from Tumblr app registration
private static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "MY_CONSUMER_KEY";
private static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "MY_SECRET_KEY";
private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "tumblrdemo://tumblrdemo.com/ok";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // To get the oauth token after the user has granted permissions
    Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
    if (uri != null) {

        String token = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_token");
        String verifier = uri.getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");

        Log.v(TAG, "Token:" + token);
        Log.v(TAG, "Verifier:" + verifier);
    } else {

        CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

        // It uses this signature by default
        // consumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner());

        CommonsHttpOAuthProvider provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_URL, AUTH_URL);

        String authUrl;
        try {
            authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, CALLBACK_URL);
            Log.v(TAG, "Auth url:" + authUrl);

            startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                    Uri.parse(authUrl)));

        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Auth url:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Auth url:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Auth url:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Auth url:" + e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
 */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    Log.v(TAG, "onResume");
}
}
```

Is there any other Android SDK available for sharing photos in tumblr. What am i doing wrong..?

Comment: Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your CALLBACK_URL, may be it will solve your problem.

```
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = "oauthflow-tumblr://callback";
```